# Tensorflow No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to Tensorflow and Machine learning in general. I'm trying to create a model to detect brain tumor through MRIs.

I'm splitting the data using `validation_split`. After compiling the model when when I try to fitting using the `.fit` function I get this Error. After googling I have found I might be because I'm not passing the `y` parameter when calling the `fit` function.

**Code**:

```py
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=0.2, rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TRAIN_DIR,
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary',
    subset='training'
)

val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TRAIN_DIR,
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary',
    subset='validation'
)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        16,
        (3, 3),
        activation='relu',
        input_shape=(150, 150, 3)
    )
)
model.add(
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2)
)

...
# some more layers
...

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=None,
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)

print(model.summary())

Test = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    epochs=2,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=val_generator
)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

**Folder structure for the images**:

```
images
|
├── training
│   ├── no
│   ├── yes
├── testing
│   ├── no
│   ├── yes
```

**Exact Error Message**:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv2d/kernel:0', 'conv2d/bias:0', 'conv2d_1/kernel:0', 'conv2d_1/bias:0', 'conv2d_2/kernel:0', 'conv2d_2/bias:0', 'dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0'].
```

**Output of model.summary()**:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 148, 148, 16)      448
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 74, 74, 16)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 72, 72, 32)        4640
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 36, 36, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 34, 34, 64)        18496
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 17, 17, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 18496)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 512)               9470464
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 1026
=================================================================
Total params: 9,495,074
Trainable params: 9,495,074
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: 1)why are using  TRAIN_DIR as path for both training and validation?
2) can you give the output for "print(model.summary())" this line?

Comment: @ajayeswar 1) I'm new to ML and tensor flow I was following tensorflows documentation saw something like that and trying to implement it.

2) Output is too long to post in comments here

Comment: Could you share the tf documentation you are using to run this code? I am unable to infer anything from the information you shared

Comment: @ajayeswar I changed the folder structure a little bit. Made two folders `training` and `testing`. Still same error.

Comment: @ajayeswar here is the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator). I was wrong they did separate the folders, I did too and still having the same error.

Comment: in the very first line, you will be getting data of both input features(X) and also the labels(Y) right? You then need to seperate the labels part of it and store under a different variable like y_train . You then need to input both x_train and y_train to you model using .fit() method . I don't see features and labels (X and Y) seperation in your code . Could you try that?

Comment: @ajayeswar I have solved the issue. The error was because I had set `loss` to `None`. Changing that have resolved my problem. See @krenerd's answer, they explained it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you set the loss to `None`, no gradient is provided from the loss function back to your model. Modify

```
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=None,
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)
```

to

```
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='mse', # or some other loss
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)
```